# ST_Collect while computing average values

Tags: postgis

In a PostGRES/PostGIS database, I have a table "myTable" containing very large numbers of polygons (the geometry is under the column "Polygon"). Each polygon has a numerical value under the "Var1" column. They also each fall under an area stored as a string in the "Region" column.

Since these polygons are too numerous, I'd like to aggregate them according to the region they belong to.

This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT ST_Collect(Polygon) as geom FROM myTable GROUP BY Region;
```

Although, by doing that, I lose the very important values under Var1.

How can I compute the means of the values of Var1 for each polygons under the same Region, and output it in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is in the question....  just compute the average!

```sql
SELECT ST_Collect(Polygon) as geom, avg(var1)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!